# Infrastructure - Maven + Nexus

Tags: maven, active-directory, nexus

I've installed a sonatype nexus to be my maven repo. The nexus instalation is using the Active Directory to authenticate users, and the annonymous login is off.

Every user that uploads an artifact to my repo must be identifyed with a unique username, thus the AD integration.

The regular way to use this structure is to set in the `POM.xml` the Distribution Managemente tag so the artifact is sent to nexus

```
 <distributionManagement>
    ...
    <repository>
      <id>deploymentRepo</id>
      <name>Internal Releases</name>
      <url>http://nexusserver:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </repository>
    ...
  </distributionManagement>
```

In the local repo settings (`~/.m2/settings.xml`) add the username/password combo to login into nexus

```
<server>
  <id>deploymentRepo</id>
  <username>deployment</username>
  <password>deployment123</password>
 </server>
```

It's working great for me, but what I'm trying to achieve is to somehow do the auth in nexus without having to put the user password in the local repo. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve: not to store password as plain text or for user having to pass password every time it runs maven deploy command?

Password could be stored in encrypted form, as described [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html)

Or you could try to pass password on command line like below, but I haven't tried that:

```
mnv -Dpassword=deployment123 deploy
```

Comment: Thank kind fellow... my goal was to 'not store password as plain text' now im using encrypted password.

Comment: Providing passwords on the command line a a huge security risk, thay can be easily discovered with `ps` or `htop`.

Comment: Agree. It wan't clear for me from the question what the desired goal was

Answer (score 0):

Nexus 2.1 is due to be released in June and we've built a new feature to support secure authentication without requiring a clear text password in the settings.xml.